# How to pass Array of complex objects as a IN parameter in a stored procedure using JPA 2

Tags: java, arrays, jpa, stored-procedures, clob

I am trying to call an Oracle stored procedure

```
create or replace 
  procedure save_item (
                            item_arr__p in     complex_list__t,
                            status__p           out varchar2,
                            status_message__p   out varchar2) is
...
begin
...
end
```

And the complex_list__t type is defined like this:

```
create or replace 
type complex_list__t is table of simple_list__t
```

And the simple_list__t type is defined like this:

```
create or replace 
type simple_list__t  is table of varchar2(2000)
```

I want to call this procedure using JPA 2. I am not sure that JPA supports arrays as parameters.
I would like to be able to do this:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("pkg_api_wd_item.save_item");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("item_arr__p", MyComplexObject[].class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("status__p", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("status_message__p", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

query.setParameter("item_arr__p", myobjects);
query.execute();

String status = (String) query.getOutputParameterValue("status__p");
String message = (String) query.getOutputParameterValue("status_message__p");
```

I really would like to use JPA as I want my application to be agnostic (no oracle dependencies).

If it is not supported by JPA, Can I instead use a CLOB parameter instead of my array?

Answer (score 0):

You might try passing a

```
List<MyComplexObject>
```

instead of an array of them. If that doesn't work, you might try

```
List<List<String>>
```

instead of either.

Comment: the problem is that I can't find a way to pass an array altogether in the parameters of a stored procedure. The last code block is what I wish would be the way it would work. Which is passing an array of those items, but that doesn't work as far as I can see.

Comment: That's why I suggested you pass a List instead of an array.

Comment: I tried, but I get in return an exception: type cannot be null. Stack trace finishing with:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null
AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.setHibernateType(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:182)
AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.&lt;init&gt;(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:131)
AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.&lt;init&gt;(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:140)

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. We had to request a direct table access.